# How to test is google sign in works or not on flutter APP

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, google-signin, google-authentication, flutter-integration-test

I working on a flutter APP with my team. But once the ios/Runner/Info.plist change, the google sign-in was broken. I want to write a test to test this problem after this problem is solved.

### The way to re-produce this error:

1. click the "Continue":

[image]

2. Select my email:

[image]

After these steps, the APP will close immediately.

I'm trying to use an integration test to test it from preventing it broken again, But I cannot click the "Continue" button in the integration test in step 1 because that is not my flutter APP's widget. The flutter integration test seems can only manipulate the widget in the flutter APP.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the ios/Runner/Info.plist change?

do you mean after adding the CFBundleURLTypes?

if that is the case then make sure that the googleusercontent is the same in both the Info.plist and GoogleService-Info.plist.

Also try running using Xcode and check what error appears in Console when the app craches.

Comment: The google auth problem is now solved. I mainly want to find a way to click the "Continue" button and select my google account in the integration test.